# Getting error while coping only first word of lines to another text file

Tags: python, file, text-files, file-handling

Input file have hundreds of line like this

```
223 66 89 00 99 00 66 44
```

and I want to print first digit of every line from input file to( like here `223`) to output.txt

```
output = open("path/output.txt", "w+")    
for line in open("path/input filename", "r"):       
    first=line.split()
    output .write(first[0])
    output .write("\n")
```

I am getting this error -

> data.write(first[0])
> IndexError: list index out of range [Finished in
> 0.1s with exit code 1]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your error refers to variables not present in your code snippet. Please help us help you by providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your code does not write the the file named `output.txt` it is going to the file named `data.txt`.

Secondly, the exception `IndexError: list index out of range` indicates that the
list returned by split is an empty list:

```
>>> ''.split()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So you probably have some empty/blank lines in the input.

You can process the file like this to handle those empty lines:

```
with open('path/input filename') as infile, open('path/output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.strip():
            print(line.split()[0], file=outfile)
```

Comment: This worked! thank you for your answer. I corrected that filename output.txt in question.

Comment: @Priya: That's great. If you are happy with the answer you should consider upvoting and marking it as accepted. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for details.

Answer (score -1):

Use `lines = file.readlines()` to save each line of the file in a list. Also, when you open the file you are using the `"w"` flag, which is only for reading. Instead, use `"a+"` for reading and writing (use the `"a+"` flag so that you append to the file rather than rewriting the entire file, which doesn't seem like what you want). I, personally, like to use a `with` statement, as it is cleaner and also takes care of closing the file for you. The full code is:

```py
data = open("path/data.txt", "a+")
output = open("path/output.txt", "a+")
with open("path/input\ filename.txt", "r") as file: # Opening file using with statement
    lines = file.readlines() # Saving each line of the file as a list
for line in lines:
    data.write(f"{line.split(" ")[0]}\n") # Writing data
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But this code only prints out the first two whole lines into another data.txt.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot to add the [: 1] in my write statement. I hope this works now.

Comment: now this is printing out only first digit of first number(2 instead of 223)

Comment: I misinterpreted what your question was. I thought you wanted to print the first digit of each number, and there is one number on each line. After reading the question more carefully, I edited my answer to include `line.split(" ")[0]`, which will split the line at every space, and write the wrist element in the line. My apologies for the confusion.